# Link to anchor on different page from WP nav

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a navbar that links to different anchors on the startpage. and when i use the links in the nav on the startpage it smoothly scrolls to the right ID. but when i go to a sub-page/other page i want the navbar to send me directly back to the startpage and the choosen ID(anchor). i think there is some conflict with the smooth-scroll javascript but i could be wrong.

name of my custom WP-theme is: fitnesstravels.

the navbar is made of custom links from Wordpress menu ex:

url: `http://localhost:8080/fitnesstravels/#destinations`

name: Destinations

when i go to a subpage like: `http://localhost:8080/fitnesstravels/destinations/rhodos`

the menu-link in my navbar named "Destinations" is linked to the  `http://localhost:8080/fitnesstravels/#destinations` anchor (if i right klick "open link in new tab" i get send to the right place. but nothing happens when im trying simply using the menu-link.

the js:

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav a, .arrow a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-50
     }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
     });
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to achieve or what is the problem..

Comment: the problem is that my navigation dont send me back to my frontpage and the correct #anchor when im on a sub-page. nothing happens when i click the links in the menu/nav. but if i am on my frontpage the navigation works and scrolls to the right anchor div.

Comment: okay can you just target links with hashes in them like so 

$('.nav.navbar-nav a[href*="#"]').on(...);

Comment: yes, the javascript is for the "smooth scrolling" effects on all my navbar links and it works on the "landingpage".
But i think the scrolling script is whats making the links not work on sub-pages. But i might be wrong. And i dont know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you put the website on a live server so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `e.preventDefault()`.

I've done exactly what you are trying to do on a site, and in the same way you described, the only significant difference being that my smooth scroll jQuery doesn't use `preventDefault`.

This is (the relevant section of) my smooth scrolling jQuery:

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$( ".navbar" ).on( "click", "li a", function(  ) {
    var pageanchor = this.hash;
    if (pageanchor)
        $root.animate({ scrollTop: $(pageanchor).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

If I change my code to use your variable names and animation settings, it is almost identical to yours except for the `preventDefault`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav.navbar-nav a, .arrow a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        var target = this.hash;
        if (target)
            $('html, body').animate({ 
                scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-50
            }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
        });
});
```

Comment: Yeah i fought the preventDefault was the problem. but the problem still remains even if i remove the  `e.preventDefault();` from my js.

the menu links wont work unless i am on my frontpage.

Comment: Guess my browser didnt update the scroll.js fast enought :P now it works like a charm!  thx @FluffyKitten